# Is there any way to define the enumerate label in general?

Tags: enumerate, labels

If I define `numberenum` like following,

```
\newenvironment{numberenum}
{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\arabic{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii})} 
\begin{enumerate}}
{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{numberenum}
    \item depth 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item depth 2
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item depth 3
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{numberenum}
```

[image: result of code 1]

Then I can get the above result.
However, after depth 4, this code doesn't work. It's easy to redefine `\labelenumiv`, but the point is generating the label keeping this pattern until the depth limit of enumerate list.

[custom labels for enumerate beyond level 4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215517/custom-labels-for-enumerate-beyond-level-4)

This article solved a similar problem using `label*` method. But my case is more tricky because of brackets. Is there any way to define `numberenum` properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**: Ahem. I just realised that there is a way simpler method to accomplish the same thing...

The `enumitem` package has a `format` key, which is normally used to set the font of the items labels (the `font` key is an alias for it). The formatted label will look like `<format>{<label>}`, where `<format>` is the value of the `format` key and `<label>` is the value of the `label` key.

You can define a macro that wraps its argument in parentheses and use that for the `format` key, like this: (I made the labels bold to show that this is still possible, but you can't swap `\bfseries` and `\parenthesize`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{10} %% <- set the max depth to 10
\newcommand*\parenthesize[1]{(#1)}
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=.\arabic*,format=\bfseries\parenthesize,leftmargin=2em}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*} %% <- set the base level label separately

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item this is level 1
    \item this is still level 1
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item this is level 2
      \item this is still level 2
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item this is level 3
          \item this is still level 3
            \begin{enumerate}
              \item this is level 4
              \item this is still level 4
                \begin{enumerate}
                  \item this is level 5 \label{deepitem}
                  \item this is still level 5
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

This is a reference to second-to-last item: \ref{deepitem}.

\end{document}
```

[image]